# Windows Server 2016 (kernel native) docker failing to run container twice

Tags: docker, windows-container

I have a problem in a corporate environment I have not seen before. I can run a container once, then subsequent tries fail. If I reboot the host I can again run the container once.

```
> docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
PS C:\> exit
```

subsequent tries

> docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore powershell
>       C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem 0f7fdefd0c5847fff3ece0b73fca03ec5cea6591450711c030ca210ee001d68c: The system cannot find the file specified.
>   (extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"0f7fdefd0c5847fff3ece0b73fca03ec5cea6591450711c030ca210ee001d68c","Owner":"docker","VolumePath":"\\?\Volume{42202173-f5be-11e8-913a-a1276543133d}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"D:\windowsfilter\0f7fdefd0c5847fff3ece0b73fca03ec5cea6591450711c030ca210ee001d68c","Layers":[{"ID":"14d5cfd7-2142-5006-82b3-4a71f6a9f21b","Path":"D:\windowsfilter\54ebae1db3486fae1f26c0f208b42f52fdc2bf9d16c3b6c1ac32d910a570f554"},{"ID":"08f45c7b-3816-5144-a72b-8f2d60085c2d","Path":"D:\windowsfilter\59643c728676d9f6df7a1faa3640c1f25b33a605020e9cf0eaefe7a83fbf0a7f"}],"HostName":"0f7fdefd0c58","HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["30305d6e-12f4-4e52-a659-c0157bb2f369"],"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).

I have observed that the container disk has been created on the file system, and it is listed when I subsequently remove it.

```
> docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
0f7fdefd0c58
```

Because docker can create and delete it, I have concluded (maybe incorrectly) that this is not a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

We have identified it as being caused by the TrendMicro anti-virus as the team are looking into it. A ticket has been raised with TrendMicro for additional input.